# Multipass MeasureOverride() do recompute child size

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0

I have a custom Panel with custom controls which should resize like **RibbonButton**, i.e. as the available size vary I should remove / add a header, resize an inner picture, etc...

Further the custom controls are lookless control, i.e. UI/Template is defined in the style, and I use triggers to update template element.

I communicate size setting from the panel to the individual controls by using an inherited attached property (I mean UI inheritance, like *DataContext*)

When I do my multi pass `MeasureOverride()` in my panel, when I call `child.Measure()`, it's as if my items are always the **same size**!
Despite me changing the inherited attached property (and it does update inside control!)
To be clear my inside control don't resize, but when I change the inherited property, they change their UI template (to a smaller version)

Any clue how I can successfully implement **RibbonButon** and **RibbonGroupPanel** like behavior?

Comment: Post the code which you tried

Answer (score 0):

I probably didn't set the right meta data option on my inherited property!
As I managed to make it work tweaking them!

Just for clarity sake I will post below the simplest sample I could write below (which I didn't do before as, even the simplest sample, is quite long!!)

**Size123Control.cs**

```
public class Size123Control : Control
{
    static Size123Control()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Size123Control), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Size123Control)));
    }
}
```

**Size123Panel.cs**

```
public class Size123Panel : Panel
{
    public static int GetSize123(DependencyObject obj) { return (int)obj.GetValue(Size123Property); }

    public static void SetSize123(DependencyObject obj, int value) { obj.SetValue(Size123Property, value); }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Size123Property = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Size123", typeof(int), typeof(Size123Panel), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(3,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits
            | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure
            | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentMeasure
            | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange
            | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange
            ));

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        double hTot = 0, h = 0, x = 0, xMax = 0;
        foreach (UIElement child in Children)
        {
            var cs = child.DesiredSize;
            if (x > 0 && x + cs.Width > finalSize.Width)
            {
                hTot += h;
                x = 0;
                h = cs.Height;
            }
            else
            {
                if (cs.Height > h)
                    h = cs.Height;
            }
            child.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(x, hTot), cs));
            x += cs.Width;
            if (x > xMax)
                xMax = x;
        }
        return new Size(xMax, hTot + h);
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        Func<Size> measure = () =>
        {
            double hTot = 0, h = 0, x = 0, xMax = 0;
            foreach (UIElement child in Children)
            {
                child.Measure(availableSize);
                var cs = child.DesiredSize;

                if (x > 0 && x + cs.Width > availableSize.Width)
                {
                    hTot += h;
                    x = 0;
                    h = cs.Height;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (cs.Height > h)
                        h = cs.Height;
                }
                x += cs.Width;
                if (x > xMax)
                    xMax = x;
            }
            return new Size(xMax, hTot + h);
        };

        SetSize123(this, 3);
        var s1 = measure();
        if (s1.Width <= availableSize.Width && s1.Height <= availableSize.Height)
            return s1;

        SetSize123(this, 2);
        var s2 = measure();
        if (s2.Width <= availableSize.Width && s2.Height <= availableSize.Height)
            return s2;

        SetSize123(this, 1);
        var s3 = measure();

        return s3;
    }
}
```

**generic.xaml**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Size123Control}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Size123Control}">
                <Border x:Name="MAIN" Width="48" Height="48" Background="Red" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray"/>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="local:Size123Panel.Size123" Value="2">
                        <Setter TargetName="MAIN" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="MAIN" Property="Width" Value="32"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="MAIN" Property="Height" Value="32"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="local:Size123Panel.Size123" Value="1">
                        <Setter TargetName="MAIN" Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="MAIN" Property="Width" Value="16"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="MAIN" Property="Height" Value="16"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**main.xaml**

```
<local:Size123Panel>
    <local:Size123Control/>
    <local:Size123Control/>
    <local:Size123Control/>
    <local:Size123Control/>
    <local:Size123Control/>
    <local:Size123Control/>
    <local:Size123Control/>
    <local:Size123Control/>
    <local:Size123Control/>
    <local:Size123Control/>
    <local:Size123Control/>
    <local:Size123Control/>
    <local:Size123Control/>
</local:Size123Panel>
```